# Print user groups

Tags: python, django

I would like to print information about all my users and their groups in a template, like this:

```
        {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
          <td>(there should be enumerate here - 1,2,3,4 etc...)</td>
          <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
          <td>
          {% for group in user.groups %}
          {{ group }}, </td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

but it doesn't work:

> 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

I have two additional questions:
**1. How can I easily enumerate users, like this:**

```
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Kowalski</td>
      <td>John</td>
      ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
      ...
    </tr>
         ...
```

**2. How can I print groups like this:**

> group1, group2, group3

instead

> group1, group2, group3,
>   (last comma is wrong)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do everything you are asking for:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
        <td>
            {% for group in user.groups.all %}
                {{ group }}
                {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %} 
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Check out the following link from the official docs for more information about builtin forloop variables: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Answer (score 3):

you should change

```
{% for group in user.groups.all %}
{{group}}
```